# Principal argument of $-2i$

Tags: complex-numbers

> How to write the principal argument of $-2i$ ?

I cannot just write $-\pi/2$, altough it is obvious, I have to justify it somehow. Can I say that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\arctan\left({\frac {-2}x}\right)$ ?

Comment: If it is obvious why cannot you "just write that"? It **indeed** is obvious, in particular if you already defined the principal argument as an angle in $\;[0,2\pi)\;$ .

Comment: I agree with @Timbuc.  I would simply write "obviously $\operatorname{Arg}(-2i) = -\pi/2$", perhaps noting that it lies on the negative imaginary axis.

Comment: @Timbuc the interval is $(-\pi, \pi]$

Comment: @OBDA That's fine just as well: exactly the same.

Comment: @Timbuc OK, I agree, shall I delete the question ?

Comment: @OBDA Not at all. These things can help others as well with little doubts. In fact, I forgot to upvote your question, so now I do it.

Comment: @OBDA It depends on how you calculate the principal argument, but usually it is done by [atan$2$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation), from which it, of course, is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, for any branch of the logarithm function determines a branch of the complex logarithm and vice versa, via
$$\arg z = \Im \log z$$
Now, if we take the branch of $\arg$ that takes values in $(-\pi, \pi]$, then for complex numbers $w$ with imaginary part in that range, we have $\log \exp w = w$. In particular, if we can find such a $w$ such that $\exp w = -2i$, then we will have
$$\arg (-2i) = \Im \log (-2i) = \Im \log \exp w = \Im w.$$
Now, certainly $$w = \log 2 - \frac{\pi}{2} i$$ satisfies these conditions, so $$\arg (-2i) = -\frac{\pi}{2}$$ as desired.

NB that the argument doesn't depend on the real part of $w$, so it is enough to determine the imaginary part of a $w$ that meets the criteria.